# Scala Play thread

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, scala, future

I'm currently using Scala / Play2 framework / MongoDB (reactivemongo)
I have a function in a request doing like this : find maximum value in a collection, increase the that maximum number by a random, and save the new value to that collection, and return the new value.

```
def generateCode():Future[String] = {
  // find maximum
  maximum = Future[].... map { maxValue =>
      // increase maxValue
      newValue = maxValue + random
      // save back to database
  }
}
```

The problem is I want this code is only 1 thread run at a time. Because if 2 thread run this a same time, then value con be conflicted.
Example:
thread 1: read max = 100, thread 2 read max = 100
thread 1: increase max = 105, thread 2 increase max = 102
thread 1: save 105 to db, thread 2 save 102 to db

finally the maximum in db is 102, in actually it should be 105.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule ReactiveMongo API and operations on Future require implicit ExecutionContext in scope. So what you can do is define a single threaded execution context and use it in the class where you defined your `generateCode()` method and in the class where you call ReactiveMongo API.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
```

You can also pass `ec` explicitly to the methods that require implicit ExecutionContext. You just need to make sure the whole chain of asynchronous method calls uses the same single threaded execution context.

Comment: I use this approach and it look fine when it access the generateCode method in same thread. But how to make the future call inside also use that thread?

Comment: Using the same implicit instance of ExecutionContext in all places you expect single threaded behavior should work. To be explicit you can pass `ec` directly to to the methods that require ExecutionContext as implicit parameter. E.g. `Future[].... map { maxValue => /*...*/ } (ec)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Semaphore` or `ReentrantLock` to implement lock:

```
val s = new ReentrantLock() 

def generateCode():Future[String] = {
  s.lock()  //get lock block other threads to execute the db operation      
  // find maximum
  maximum = Future[].... map { maxValue =>

      // increase maxValue
      newValue = maxValue + random
      // save back to database
  }
  s.unlock()///after finish db operation, release this lock for other threads can get the Semaphore to continue work
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but  finding maximum is the Future call, so should we put the s.unlock() inside the map function ?

Comment: Yeah, you can try minimize your lock scope to increase cpu usage

Comment: I put the s.unlock() inside the callback, and it throws IllegalMonitorStateException

Comment: The lock should be released when the Future completes or inside the Future right after write to DB is finished. `ReentrantLock` doesn't allow to release the lock in a different thread, that's why `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown. `Semaphore` should work though